# How to marshal an array of unsigned short (c++) -> ushort (c#) or read a native array to create BitmapSource?

Tags: c#, c++, interop

There is no overload to copy the data from a native array of `unsigned short` to a managed array of `ushort`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=netframework-4.8

How should this be achieved ?

- marshal to `byte[]` then fuse 2 bytes to an ushort ? how ?
- marshal to `short[]` then cast to `ushort[]` ?

The code for the second solution would be (with `unsafe`):

```
var imageArray16 = new short[GetSize()];
Marshal.Copy(imageFeaturesPack.Data, imageArray16, 0, GetSize());
var imageArray16Converted = imageArray16.Select(o => *((ushort*)(void*)&o)).ToArray();
Bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(Width, Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb48, null,
    imageArray16Converted, GetStride());
```

But any of those adds complexity.

By goal is to copy a c++ image `unsigned short[]` to a BitmapSource such as:

```
var array = new short[GetSize()]; //GetSize() => width*height*colors;
Marshal.Copy(nativeDataPointer, array, 0, GetSize());
Bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(Width, Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb48, null, array,
    GetStride()); //GetStride() => width*colors;
```

Could I eventually read directly the native array from its pointer to create the BitmapSource ?

Comment: The size of the array is unlikely to be correct, when GetSize() pays attention to "colors" then it is probably twice too big.  Just don't use an array at all, use the Create() overload that takes an IntPtr so you can pass nativeDataPointer directly.  Most critical detail is the PixelFormats value, it must match the way the C++ code writes the pixel values, Rbg48 sounds awfully optimistic.

Comment: When I use an array of `unsigned short[width*height*colors]` in the native side, I don't see why GetSize() would be wrong. Also, I don't undertand the "Rgb48 being awfully optimistic"; I know for certain I'm writing pixels like this: rgbrgbrgb.. .

Comment: Anyway, on the native side I added a cuda kernel to convert to an `unsigned char[width*height*colors]`, since anyway WPF will convert a 16bits image to a 8bits one. The only way to keep the data would be to inject directly the cuda image on device to a DX12 quad or something, and inject the DX12 display into the WPF GUI. All this being said, that would a good thing to solve the OP problem.

Comment: Right, unsigned char is byte in C#, not short.  So twice too big.  And rgbrgbrgb would be PixelFormats.Rgb24.  You never described a problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: I agree with you that if I read the content from the nativeDataPointer as array of bytes I need twice the size; however here, I'm using the overload of BitmapSource.Create that reads the data as array of short, hence GetSize() is correct. The problem I'm trying to solve is to use this managed array of short as array of ushort and create the BitmapSource from that.

Comment: @HansPassant NB: in the first sentence I indicate that I'm starting with an `unsigned short[]`